# Set Parameters to persistent values

Tags: java, null, static-methods

I have read up on it a bit and I understand that in java you can't change the original value of given parameters and expect those to persist after the method is over. But I'd really like to know a good way to do this. Could someone give me some pointers on what I could do to make this method work? Thanks.

```
/**
* This will set values in the given array to be "" (or empty strings) if they are null values
*
* @param checkNull
*/
public static void setNullValuesBlank(String... checkNull) {
  for (int i = 0; i < checkNull.length; i++) {
    String check = checkNull[i];
    if (check == null) {
      check = "";
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

So I have to set it to the array as several people mentioned, and it works great if I construct the array in the first place, but if I don't then it doesn't work.

Here's the fixed method:

```
/**
  * This will set values in the given array to be "" (or empty strings) if they are null values
  *
  * @param checkNull
  */
public static void setNullValuesBlank(String... checkNull) {
  for (int i = 0; i < checkNull.length; i++) {
    if (checkNull[i] == null) {
      checkNull[i] = "";
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a call where it works:

```
String s = null;
String a = null;
String[] arry = new String[]{s, a};
for (int i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(i + ": " + arry[i]);
}
setNullValuesBlank(arry);
for (int i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(i + ": " + arry[i]);
}
```

Here's a call where it **doesn't** work, but I want it to:

```
String q = null;
String x = null;
System.out.println("q: " + q);
System.out.println("x: " + x);
setNullValuesBlank(q, x);
System.out.println("q: " + q);
System.out.println("x: " + x);
```

Output of that:

```
q: null
x: null
q: null
x: null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign to the array:

```
if (checkNull[i] == null) {
  checkNull[i] = "";
}
```

Assigning to the check will not change the array.

Comment: Is there any way for me to not have to construct the array in the first place?

Comment: You need to construct it, since in normal var args, you have the same problem as in the original scenario, since an array with the objects from the parameters is constructed for the method call.

Comment: I'm not totally sure I follow you and I don't understand why it wouldn't work, but I think you're right, unfortunately...

Comment: +1 for `an array with the objects from the parameters is constructed for the method call`.

Comment: Is there no reference to the original variables? Because I want to be able to call this method on a couple variables at once and then immediately do something with those same variables without having to create an array and then use the array to process the variables... I just use this method a lot and the purpose of methods is to cut work ;) But if it's a limitation in the way Java works then I can deal with that and I'll just handle it. (Thanks by the way)

Comment: Java (as many other language) is pass by value, not by reference, so while you can use objects passed to a method, you are not able to assign a new object to those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void setNullValuesBlank(String... checkNull)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < checkNull.length; i++) if(checkNull[i] == null) checkNull[i] = "";
}
```

Comment: Is there any way for me to not have to construct the array in the first place?

Comment: @kentcdodds Yes, pass the strings each as a parameter, i.e `setNullValuesBlank(str1, str2, str3);`

Comment: @kentcdodds umm, not expected that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the value to the array:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class NullCheck {

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
        final String[] sa = { null, null };
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( sa ) );
        check( sa );
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( sa ) );
    }

    private static void check( final String... a ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
            if ( a[i] == null ) a[i] = "";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any way for me to not have to construct the array in the first place?